# Regarding Java subclasses inheriting methods that return "this"

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, subclassing

Have a class `Car` with a public method

```
public Car myself() {
  return this;
}
```

Have a subclass `Ferrari`, and a variable `foo` that contains a `Ferrari` object.

Finally,

```
Ferrari bar = foo.myself();
```

This will warn you, because the method `myself()` returns a `Car` object, rather than the expected `Ferrari`.

*Note:* I know that the example is stupid because you'd just do `bar = foo`. It's just an example.

---

Solutions:

- Override the `myself()` method in `Ferrari`.
- Cast the `Car` object to a `Ferrari` object when assigning `bar`.

---

Both solutions work and I am okay with that. However, the first one is undesirable when you have several subclasses of `Car`. I feel that overriding a method over and over defeats the point of inheriting it. Next, regarding the second solution, casting is not pretty. It feels silly - if my variable is of type `Ferrari`, shouldn't Java be able to implicitly cast it without warning me? After all, Java must know that the returned object *can* be casted to `Ferrari`, no?

---

Is there another workaround? Just out of curiosity - I can live with casting stuff, telling Java what things are supposed to be...

Comment: Surely out of the two options you give, overriding is a better solution than casting?

Comment: @NathanCooper: Maybe, perhaps, dunno. Just wondering if there is another way.

Comment: This is somewhat tricky to give a practical answer to, as your `myself` example is not a practical use-case.  Do you have a more realistic scenario?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Method chaining is a use (and the only one I can think of). It is really a syntactical issue addressed using OO concepts but it is useful at making code better understandable and maintainable in the Builder pattern, or in JAXB generated classes, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution uses generics in a way that is used more often in the Java libraries.

It works and you don't have to cast the result every time nor override the `myself` method in every subclass.

I believe that it is the only solution that doesn't require overriding or casting. It does require each subclass to use its own type as a type parameter to the superclass `Car`: `class Ferrari extends Car<Ferrari>`

```
class Car<X extends Car<X>> {
    public X myself() {
        return (X) this;
    }
}

class Ferrari extends Car<Ferrari> {
}
```

And then use it as you intended:

```
Ferrari testarossa = new Ferrari().myself();
```

This concept is used in the Java standard libraries a few times as well in one way or another:

**`java.lang.Enum`**

```
public abstract class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

**`java.util.Comparable`**

```
public interface Comparable<T>
```

(You're supposed to pass your own class type when you implement a comparable: `class ShoeSize implements Comparable<ShoeSize>`)

**Method chaining**

There's a good use for this too - there is a pattern, favored by some, that allows method chaining. This is what `StringBuilder` does: `new StringBuilder().append("a").append("b").toString()`. However a class that supports method chaining is often hard to subclass. Using the approach I outlined above makes it possible to subclass in this situation.

Comment: If my class declaration is `class Car <A extends B>`, using your suggestion it would be like `class Car <Z extends Car<Z>, A extends B>`? Eclipse says *"Incorrect number or arguments.. it cannot be parametrized for <Z>"*

Comment: `class Car <Z extends Car<Z, A>, A extends B>`. Generics can get ugly. I just don't know any other way.

Comment: By the way, it gives a warning for unchecked type cast when it returns this. Can something be done about it? I'm kinda ok with it anyway.

Comment: You can add the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the method.

Comment: Thank you. Do the Java generic classes do that too, though?

Comment: No, the Java library just lets the warnings in place. Take method `getDeclaringClass` from class `java.lang.Enum`. You can copy it to the `Car` class if you change `Class<E>` to `Class<X>`. You'll see that it has three compilation warnings that are related to generics.

Comment: Well that's just... okay. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This also depends on how you know the `foo` variable.

If you know it by

```
Ferrari foo = new Ferrari();
```

then an overridden method like

```
class Ferrari extends Car {
    @Override
    public Ferrari myself() { 
        return this;
    }
}
```

will allow you to exploit the covaraince, and you can do

```
Ferrari foo = new Ferrari();
Ferrari bar = foo.myself();
```

although there are probably not many application cases where this makes sense: When you already know that it is a Ferrari, you could just write

```
Ferrari bar = foo;
```

The situation is different when you only know it by

```
Car foo = new Ferrari();
```

Then you're out of luck: You don't know the runtime type any more, and you'll have to cast anyhow.

(Note: Such an overridden method returning `this` with a more specific type has a real application case when it comes to self-referential generic types. This is sometimes referred to as the [getThis trick](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206))

Concerning your statement

> It feels silly - if my variable is of type Ferrari, shouldn't Java be able to implicitly cast it without warning me? After all, Java must know that the returned object can be casted to Ferrari, no?

This is not true. No one prevents you from overriding the method like

```
class Ferrari extends Car {
    @Override
    public Car myself() { 
        return new Volkswagen(); 
    }
}
```

and then the cast would no longer be valid

Comment: Interesting link to the 'getThis trick' . . also +1 on down-vote explanation.

Answer (score 1):

A sub-class may override a base-classes method, and as part of that contract indicate that it will return the specific type. This provides clarity to the user of the class, whereas expecting the user to know the type being returned and cast it accordingly does not. Therefore, overriding is better.

Comment: Interestingly this is possible in Java, but fires a warning in the case of Objective-C properties, where, for example, a UIViewController's view property is overridden to return a more specific type.