# How do I return a unsure type?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have a parent Class named 'Shape' and write a method in it
I want any class extends from it can call the bigger method for other use.
simple logic like this:

```
public abstract Class Shape{
    public int size;
    public Shape() {}
    public Class<? extends Shape> bigger() {
        this.size += 1;
        return this; // ← Here,How can I return it with unsure type?
    }
}
```

but how can I return a unsure type in here ? 
thanks for any ideas!

====

and if I have a class Square extends Shape;

and I want use it like this:

```
Square S = new Square().bigger();
```

And it will return a Shape Class, not a Square Class.

but I don't wanna use: (Square) new Square.bigger();

I hope it can automatic recognize what Class a using this method

And return the correct type.

Comment: You can just return Shape. All things that extend shapes are also shapes. It's a reference that gets returned so there isn't any loss of information. I believe this is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41525783/how-to-cleanly-handle-unchecked-conversion-with-generics-in-an-interface

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regarding Java subclasses inheriting methods that return "this"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23041693/regarding-java-subclasses-inheriting-methods-that-return-this)

Comment: You have to spell keywords​ like `class` exactly correctly if you intend your code to compile. You cannot declare a method to return one type, like `Class`, and return a different type. Check out the official Java Tutorial for how these should be done.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have much more to learn XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not sure what is the "unsure" type, but in java we have the Generic type which is Java can return any class regardless what they are.

for example

```
public interface dbDao<T>{

    public T t; //this is generic class, all class can use this method  

}
```

i hope you understand what im trying to say.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need!

Comment: nice to help u sir. by the way, can u vote the answer. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can override `bigger()` method which returns `Square` (not `Shape`).
It is regal.

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public int size;
    public Shape() {}
    public Shape bigger() {
        this.size += 1;
        return this; // ← Here,How can I return it with unsure type?
    }
}

public class Square extends Shape {
    @Override
    public Square bigger() { // returns Square, not Shape
        return this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't return a `Class` here, just a `Shape`. Something like,

```
public abstract class Shape { // <- class
    public int size;

    public Shape() {
    }

    public Shape bigger() { // <-- a Shape. By definition of a sub-class because
        this.size += 1; // <-- "this" class is abstract
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it make me another idea for my problem. But, I really want to know that is there any way can let me return an unsure type?

Comment: `public abstract class Shape<T> {` and return a `Shape<T>` from `bigger()`. I guess the real question is, what do you mean by "an unsure type"? `Object`?

Answer (score 0):

In Java, when you override a method you can actually be more specific than the interface requires. For example, the interface requires bigger returns a Shape, but a Square class that extends from Shape could return a Square since a Square is a Shape. This means if you assign it to a Square variable, there is no need to cast when you call bigger.

```
public abstract class Shape { // class not Class
    public int size;

    public Shape bigger() {
        this.size += 1;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Square extends Shape {
    @Override
    public Square bigger() {
        this.size += 1;
        return this;
    }
}
```

That's one way of doing it, which in this case is a little frustrating because it repeats the code. Another way of doing this, that would work in C# as well, is to use a generic with a restriction that the generic type implement itself. This is called the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

```
public abstract class Shape <S extends Shape>{
    public int size;

    public S bigger() {
        this.size += 1;
        return this;
    }
}

public class Square extends Shape<Square>{
}
```

Comment: a public constructor that does nothing does not need to be declared btw